# Eslint rule to prevent space around a typescript generic

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Which EsLint rules enforce the following correction?

```js
type Incorrect = Array< number >;
type Correct = Array<number>;
```

Every @typescript-eslint / @stylistic rule I have tried dodges it.